# MPAndroidChart line needs some explaination

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart, linechart

I need your help, kindly tell me which field will make from this

[image]

to this

[image]

Comment: Not sure, but I think the first one is a BarChart where the second is a LineChart, they have a slight different implementation, but implements the same abstract class BarLineChartBase.java

Comment: Both are line charts...

Comment: show you code where you add your Entry values